# Rails 4.1.12 and routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I'm updating from Rails 4.1.8 to 4.1.12, and one spec is failing because of a route:

```
   expected: "https://test.host/en/name-3/activities/3-activity-around-name-3/bookings/new?booking%5Bstart_date%5D=2015-07-03+08%3A38%3A39+UTC"
        got: "https://test.host/en/name-3/activities/3-activity-around-name-3/bookings/new.name-3?booking%5Bstart_date%5D=2015-07-03+08%3A38%3A39+UTC" (using ==)
```

config/routes.rb:

```
get '*destination/activities/:id/bookings/new', to: 'bookings#new', as: :new_destination_activity_booking, constraints: DestinationConstraint.new
```

app/controllers/public/bookings_controller.rb:

```
def new
  session[:traveler_return_to] = new_destination_activity_booking_url(@activity.destination, @activity, params)
```

spec/controllers/public/bookings_controller_spec.rb:

```
session[:traveler_return_to].should == new_destination_activity_booking_url(activity.destination, activity, booking: { start_date: start_date })
```

I tested that route in Rails console and it behaves fine. How can it add ".name-3" in specs?

Comment: What is the value of `@activity.to_s` in the controller and the value of `activity.to_s` in the spec? What is the URL _supposed_ to look like (i.e. what is supposed to appear between "new" and "?booking")?

Comment: activity is the same in both cases, nothing is supposed to appear in between (i.e. expected result is the first line of rspec). I tried in rails console with the same controller params as the spec, and the route is fine... not sure what else to debug, will try a simpler test case